# i am setting session in login controller and receving in dashboard model also load session in autoload

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get username through the session in the dashboard to run queries according to for given username to retrieve his `lastname`, `firstname`, `cardname`, id, etc.

Here my login controller code I am setting session in if condition,

```
            $uname=$this->input->post('uname');
            $upass=$this->input->post('upass');

            if($this->Login_model->logauthentication($uname,$upass))
            {
                echo "inside login controller you are authorized person <br>";
                $this->db->select('addmember');
                $this->db->where('emailaddress',$uname);
                $q = $this->db->get('registration');
                $userid=$q->row()->addmember;
                if($userid)
                {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('userid',$userid);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('username',$uname);

                    $this->load->view('Users/dashboard');
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "you are member<br>";
                    $this->session->set_userdata('userid',$userid);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('username',$uname);
                    $this->load->view('Users/dashboard');
                }
            }
```

And my dashboard model code is

```
echo $this->session->userdata('username');
exit;
```

I am also loading session library in autoload.
It's nothing printed.

Comment: uname  is user inputted value and userid is database column value where addmember =1

Comment: Please title the query appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Please check to see whether the session has been initiated or not

### dashboard model

### if (!isset($this->session->userdata['username'])) {echo 'test';exit;}